# How can I generate following arm assembler output using ARM gcc 7.3?

Tags: c, assembly, arm

```
myfunction:
@ Function supports interworking.
@ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
@ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
@ link register save eliminated.
mul r3, r0, r0
mov r0, r3
mla r0, r1, r0, r2
bx  lr
```

I am able to generate everything except for the mov instruction using following C function.

```
int myfunction(int r0, int r1, int r2, int r3)
{
  r3 = r0*r0;
  r0 = r3;
  r3 = r0;
  return (r1*r3)+r2;
}
```

How can I instruct r3 to be set to the address of r0 in assembly code?

Comment: When you say that you "are able to generate everything except for the mov instruction", are you generating the assembler using the gcc tools?

Comment: Your code makes no sense. The `r0=r3` is useless and the compiler understands that. Your assembly code could just use `r3` instead of `r0` in the `mla` source thereby avoiding the `mov` altogether.

Comment: The easiest way to get the desired result is to use inline assembly.  Generally, the compilers output is not predictable down to the exact registers and instructions chosen.  The most productive way to force the compiler to emit certain instructions is to use inline assembly, other ways are generally rather futile.

Comment: Echoing others - the given assembly is non-optimal so the compiler is doing you a favor.  If you don't want the compiler's help, then you need to do the work yourself.  Best way to easily do that is with inline assembler, though occasionally intrinsic calls will be sufficient.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: Nobody would call [gcc's inline assembler](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html) easy to use, surely?

Comment: have you been told this is possible? maybe there is an optimization bug in that specific version of gcc that is being exploited.  If that is the case then you need to look at the gcc source code to figure this out.

Comment: To be fair optimizers do a good job but they dont think like we do there are often places and generally large projects have many missed optimizations, something like this though, having tried it, the compiler is not having a problem here.  Using the words optimization bug in the prior comment is really not fair.   Nuance or feature are better ways to say that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
unsigned int myfunction(unsigned int a, unsigned int  b, unsigned int c)
{
  return (a*a*b)+c;
}
```

Your choices are going to be something like this

```
00000000 <myfunction>:
   0:   e52db004    push    {r11}       ; (str r11, [sp, #-4]!)
   4:   e28db000    add r11, sp, #0
   8:   e24dd014    sub sp, sp, #20
   c:   e50b0008    str r0, [r11, #-8]
  10:   e50b100c    str r1, [r11, #-12]
  14:   e50b2010    str r2, [r11, #-16]
  18:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [r11, #-8]
  1c:   e51b2008    ldr r2, [r11, #-8]
  20:   e0010392    mul r1, r2, r3
  24:   e51b200c    ldr r2, [r11, #-12]
  28:   e0000291    mul r0, r1, r2
  2c:   e51b3010    ldr r3, [r11, #-16]
  30:   e0803003    add r3, r0, r3
  34:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
  38:   e28bd000    add sp, r11, #0
  3c:   e49db004    pop {r11}       ; (ldr r11, [sp], #4)
  40:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

or this

```
00000000 <myfunction>:
   0:   e0030090    mul r3, r0, r0
   4:   e0202391    mla r0, r1, r3, r2
   8:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

as you have probably figured out.

The mov should never be considered by the compiler backend as it just wastes an instruction.  r3 goes into the mla no need to put it in r0 then do the mla.  Not quite sure how to get the compiler to do more.  Even this doesn't encourage it

```
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a )
{
    return(a*a);
}
unsigned int myfunction(unsigned int a, unsigned int  b, unsigned int c)
{
  return (fun(a)*b)+c;
}
```

giving

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e1a03000    mov r3, r0
   4:   e0000093    mul r0, r3, r0
   8:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

0000000c <myfunction>:
   c:   e0030090    mul r3, r0, r0
  10:   e0202391    mla r0, r1, r3, r2
  14:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

Basically if you don't optimize you get nowhere near what you were after.  If you optimize that mov shouldn't be there, should be easy to optimize out.

While some level of manipulation of writing high level code to encourage the compiler to output low level code is possible, trying to get this exact output is not something you should expect to be able to do.

Unless you use inline asm

```
asm
(
   "mul r3, r0, r0\n"
   "mov r0, r3\n"
   "mla r0, r1, r0, r2\n"
   "bx lr\n"
);
```

giving your result

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   e0030090    mul r3, r0, r0
   4:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
   8:   e0202091    mla r0, r1, r0, r2
   c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

or real asm

```
mul r3, r0, r0
mov r0, r3
mla r0, r1, r0, r2
bx lr
```

and feed it into gcc rather than as (arm-whatever-gcc so.s -o so.o)

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   e0030090    mul r3, r0, r0
   4:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
   8:   e0202091    mla r0, r1, r0, r2
   c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

so that technically you were using gcc on the command line but gcc does some preprocessing and then feeds it to as.

Unless you find a core or where Rd and Rs have to be the same register and can then specify that core/bug/whatever on the gcc command line, I don't see the mov happening, maybe, just maybe, with clang/llvm compile fun and myfunction separately to bytecode then combine them then optimize then output to the target then examine that.  I would hope either in the optimization or the output that the mov would be optimized out but you might get lucky.

### Edit

I made an error:

```
unsigned int myfunction(unsigned int a, unsigned int  b, unsigned int c)
{
  return (a*a*b)+c;
}

arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc --version
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <myfunction>:
   0:   e0030090    mul r3, r0, r0
   4:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
   8:   e0202091    mla r0, r1, r0, r2
   c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

but this

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc --version
arm-none-eabi-gcc (GCC) 8.2.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -c so.c -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.o

so.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <myfunction>:
   0:   e0030090    mul r3, r0, r0
   4:   e0202391    mla r0, r1, r3, r2
   8:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

I'll have to build a 7.3 or go find one. Somewhere between 5.x.x and 8.x.x the backend changed or...

Note you may need -mcpu=arm7tdmi or -mcpu=arm9tdmi or -march=armv4t or -march=armv5t on the command line depending on the default target (cpu/arch) built into your compiler.  Or you might get something like this

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <myfunction>:
   0:   fb00 f000   mul.w   r0, r0, r0
   4:   fb01 2000   mla r0, r1, r0, r2
   8:   4770        bx  lr
   a:   bf00        nop
```

this

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc --version
arm-none-eabi-gcc (GCC) 7.3.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

produces

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <myfunction>:
   0:   e0030090    mul r3, r0, r0
   4:   e0202391    mla r0, r1, r3, r2
   8:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

So you may have to work backward to find the version where it changed, the source code change to gcc that caused it and modify 7.3.0 making something that is not really 7.3.0 but reports as 7.3.0 and outputs your desired code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast response. This helps really much thank you! It worked when I used the function you provided with -mcpu=arm6 set.

I found a nice Compiler Explorer in the meantime which makes my life easier a lot as well - just for people facing this problem in the future - visit https://godbolt.org/

Comment: a lot of folks use godbolt.org yes I dont which is why I forget its there for a quicky test.  again never assume what the compiler is going to do, you can iterate against a specific compiler and encourage it to do things but dont rely on those things to happen, dont rely on a compiler to produce the above code either version, they might not even use mla, might break it into multiple instructions...you are right though godbolt is a good resource for this exercise.

Comment: That was a lot of help for a simple problem.  Well done.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan not that much work, and it was fun to do.